# RegEx to find numbers over certain value with commas, and another text value, on same line

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regular Expressions, and I have been trying to figure out how to code this:  I need to find numbers greater than 25000 where the same line also has the number " 19" somewhere on that line (that's a space then 19).  The problem is that the numbers have commas in them.  I tried a few options:

This finds lines with any numbers over 25000:

`^.*(25,|26,|27,|28,|29,|30,|31,|32,|33,|34,|35,|36,|37,|38,|39,|40,|41,|42,|43,|44,|45,|46,|47,|48,|49,|50,|51,|52,|53,|54,|55,|56,|57,|58,|59,|60,|61,|62,|63,|64,|65,|66,|67,|68,|69,|70,|71,|72,|73,|74,|75,|76,|77,|78,|79,|80,|81,|82,|83,|84,|85,|86,|87,|88,|89,|90,|91,|92,|93,|94,|95,|96,|97,|98,|99,|100,|101,|102,|103,|104,|105,|106,|107,|108,|109,|110,|111,|112,|113,|114,|115,|116,|117,|118,|119,|120,|121,|122,|123,|124,).*$`

This finds line with both `" 19"` and `26`, (but not with the comma behind the `26`)
`^.*( 19.*26).*$`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you include sample input, expected output and also mention regex tool/flavor you're using

Comment: This does not look like a good problem for a regular expression to solve. I would consider using a programming language to split your input up into a data structure and then loop through the lines to check for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers over 25000 can be represented as follows :

```
\d{6,}|2[5-9]\d{3}|[3-9]\d{4}
```

That is, in english :

- numbers of 6 digits or more
- numbers of 5 digits starting with 2 and another digit equal or greater than 5
- numbers of 5 digits starting with a digit greater than 2

So the complete regex would look like this :

```
.*(\d{6,}|2[5-9]\d{3,}|[3-9]\d{4,}).* 19.*
```

Which is said number somewhere in the line, followed by `19` somewhere in the line.

Here is a [test run on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gN4kO5/2) for you to test with your data.

I also second the comment that this isn't a job for regular expressions, which as you can see work on characters rather than numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

`^(([0-9,]*([3-9][0-9]|2[5-9]),?[0-9]{3})\s?)$`

That should handle the numeric part. You didn't really explain if the " 19" would come before or after that, and what would delimit that from the numeric part, but just insert `(\s19)` wherever that bit needs to go.

[example](https://regex101.com/r/kP6sQ8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  The following RegEx worked for me:

^.* 19.*(25,|26,|27,|28,|29,|30,|31,|32,|33,|34,|35,|36,|37,|38,|39,|40,|41,|42,|43,|44,|45,|46,|47,|48,|49,|50,|51,|52,|53,|54,|55,|56,|57,|58,|59,|60,|61,|62,|63,|64,|65,|66,|67,|68,|69,|70,|71,|72,|73,|74,|75,|76,|77,|78,|79,|80,|81,|82,|83,|84,|85,|86,|87,|88,|89,|90,|91,|92,|93,|94,|95,|96,|97,|98,|99,|100,|101,|102,|103,|104,|105,|106,|107,|108,|109,|110,|111,|112,|113,|114,|115,|116,|117,|118,|119,|120,|121,|122,|123,|124,).*$

This finds lines that have " 19" first in the line then a number greater than 25K later in the line, when the numbers have commas in them.  I couldn't use the shortcut "number ranges" that were suggested because there are other numbers on the lines without commas that are over 25K that I don't want to flag.  Maybe there's any easier way that my brute force method, but if not, at least this works.  Thanks again!